# How to detect an object of interest in a particular location of the image when there are multiple instances of the object?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, yolov5

I am training YOLOv5 object detection model using transfer learning and PyTorch framework. The goal is to detect solar panels in aerial view images. In the training images, there are often times multiple instances of solar panels. The center of the image is usually the house that the image corresponds to, but the neighbors roofs appear on the left and the right edges of a given image.

I've labeled all solar panel instances in each image. When running inference in the future, I only want to know if the roof in the center has solar panels and don't care about the houses on the edges of the image. How would I go about implementing this?

Here is an example image containing multiple instances of solar panels. The goal is to extract the detected object(s) from the roof in the middle of the image, and ignore the roof on the left edge. For training purposes, I believe it doesn't matter where in the image the objects are, you just want to train a model to recognize what the object looks like. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

[image]

Comment: Please bring some sample images for your question

Comment: I added an example image!

Comment: And how would you know "where" the house in the middle is? In some pics it could be a small house, in others a large, wide one. The hacky solution: assume some region in the center as your focus area and if you detect BBs there, you know. The complete solution: another object detection model to find the house boundary and then you detect if your panel BB appear inside it

Comment: Train your model any don't care about location of solar panel. In inference phase check the location of the plane in your image. Does it located in image margin or in the middle of the image.

Comment: your DNN needs to locate **houses** as well (bounding box or segmentation). *then* you can discard houses that are **on the edge** of your image (and solar panels on them).